# Eloquent query builder if clause implementation

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent

I have a query like this

```
        SELECT
            `id`,
            `advert_id`,
            IF(
                `chats`.`owner_id` = ?,
                `chats`.`sender_id`,
                `chats`.`owner_id`
            ) AS `sender_id`,
            IF(
                `chats`.`owner_id` = ?,
                `chats`.`owner_access_time`,
                `chats`.`sender_access_time`
            ) AS `access_time`,
            `created_time`
        FROM
            `chats`
        WHERE 1
            AND `id` = ?
            AND `owner_id` = ?
            AND `project_id` = ?
        UNION
        SELECT
            `id`,
            `advert_id`,
            IF(
                `chats`.`owner_id` = ?,
                `chats`.`sender_id`,
                `chats`.`owner_id`
            ) AS `sender_id`,
            IF(
                `chats`.`owner_id` = ?,
                `chats`.`owner_access_time`,
                `chats`.`sender_access_time`
            ) AS `access_time`,
            `created_time`
        FROM
            `chats`
        WHERE 1
            AND `id` = ?
            AND `sender_id` = ?
            AND `project_id` = ?
        ORDER BY `id` ASC
```

i am trying to implement it with eloquent query builder like this

```
    $chats = $database
        ->table('chats')
        ->where('sender_id', '=', $arguments['user_id'])
        ->union(
            $database
                ->table('chats')
                ->where('owner_id', '=', $arguments['user_id'])
                ->get(
                    [
                        'advert_id',
                        'owner_id',
                        'sender_id',
                        'id'
                    ]
                )
        )
        ->get(
            [
                'advert_id',
                'owner_id',
                'sender_id',
                'id'
            ]
        );
```

But i am getting error **Method getBindings does not exist.**, also i can't find how to write "if" clause with eloquent, all i find is **when** method, but as far as i understood it works just for "if argument exist, add additional clause to your query", what is not what i need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution

```
    $chats = $database::table('chats')
        ->where('sender_id', '?')
        ->select(
            'id',
            'advert_id',
            $database::raw('
                IF(
                    `chats`.`owner_id` = ?,
                    `chats`.`sender_id`,
                    `chats`.`owner_id`
                ) AS `sender_id`
            '),
            $database::raw('
                IF(
                    `chats`.`owner_id` = ?,
                    `chats`.`owner_access_time`,
                    `chats`.`sender_access_time`
                ) AS `access_time`
            ')
        )
        ->setBindings(
            [
                $arguments['user_id'],
                $arguments['user_id'],
                $arguments['user_id'],
            ]
        )
        ->union(
            $database::table('chats')
                ->where('owner_id', '?')
                ->select(
                    'id',
                    'advert_id',
                    $database::raw('
                        IF(
                            `chats`.`owner_id` = ?,
                            `chats`.`sender_id`,
                            `chats`.`owner_id`
                        ) AS `sender_id`
                    '),
                    $database::raw('
                        IF(
                            `chats`.`owner_id` = ?,
                            `chats`.`owner_access_time`,
                            `chats`.`sender_access_time`
                        ) AS `access_time`
                    ')
                )
                ->setBindings(
                    [
                        $arguments['user_id'],
                        $arguments['user_id'],
                        $arguments['user_id'],
                    ]
                )
        )
        ->get();
```